# How to build and distribute binary packages with nix?

Tags: nix

Naively one would expect that the core functionality of a package manager is "building packages". With nix the situation seems to be a little different: One distributes nix-files/expression (in channels or .nix files) which define derivations (`nix-instantiate`) which can be built (`nix-build`) to produce binary artifacts which are installed (`nix-env -i`) into an environment. At no point a traditional "package file" containing the built artifacts is produced, that can be copied to different machines and/or distributed e.g. as GitHub-releases.

Question:

1. Is it possible to produce binary packages (i.e. pre-built derivations) with nix tooling?
2. If not, is this an intentional omission or just a missing feature.

Comment: Nix has a native serialization format for store objects, NAR. This is how substitutions are pulled from the cache, f/e.

Comment: (if you didn't wait for hours while your system installed NixOS or updated packages, the reason you didn't is because it was able to get those packages prebuilt by Hydra; you ran run your own cache just as well).

Comment: You are probably looking for a combination of `nix-copy-closure` (which can transfer derivations and their dependencies from one machine to another) and a Nix [binary cache](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Binary_Cache).

Comment: To be clear, distributing binaries as github releases would be frowned on. One of the core advantages of Nix is that its design allows the user to have a great deal of certainty that their packages were built from the sources, and via the steps, that they _claim_ to be built by and with (at least, when using binary caches that one rightfully trusts). Anything that you got off some random project's github is a lot more likely to be tampered with than something from Hydra (which has a small, paranoid team of maintainers).

Comment: Also, because Nix doesn't make the... let's say, _optimistic_... assumptions about binary compatibility that are made by most other distros and packaging tools, a binary in the Nix world is specific not just to a given distro release, but a _specific pin_ of that distro release; as soon as nixpkgs changes anything in the dependency chain of your binary, continuing to use that binary will require users to have both the old version and a newer version of that dependency in their local store.

Comment: By the way -- for high-level questions about Nix and the principles behind its design, I really, _really_ recommend keeping [Eelco's doctoral thesis](https://edolstra.github.io/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf) on speed dial. Old as it is, and much active development as there has been in the intervening years, it answers everything discussed here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thx, NAR files are a great hint! I'll try to see if I can build them myself.

Comment: @chepner Yes exactly, a combination of nix-copy-closure and a binary cache comes close to the described goal. Is something like this available?

Comment: @HeinrichHartmann, ...if you're running a binary cache you don't need `nix-copy-closure` to retrieve things from it -- the client just needs to add that cache to their `substituters` list, and operations that would involve builds (and where the derivation isn't explicitly configured to _prefer_ a local build, which is a flag that's often set for things that are so fast to build that a cache check would slow it down, or so large that a download would be slower than a local build, or likely to be unique to each system where it's deployed, etc) will check the cache for a prebuilt version first.

Comment: @HeinrichHartmann, ...honestly, if you want a binary cache to be useful, I would probably try to build the software in that cache as a flake; that way the derivation should stay stable enough to resolve to the prebuilt binaries' hashes every time.

Comment: (btw, because Nix searches for software in binary caches based on a hash of the inputs and build steps, that means that to use a binary cache, you need to give your users enough information to be able to build the software without that cache. This is very much considered a feature-not-a-bug).

Comment: Thanks Charles, I'll look into binary caches for sharing builds between my machines. However, the larger question of distributing binary nix packages is not addressable by these means. I want to give my users a simple, fast, stand-alone way to install pre-built packages. Modifying local nix configuration (e.g. substituters) is not viable for this use-case.

Comment: Really, I'd bring the question to NixOS Discourse. My personal take, though? Bad practice, intentionally unsupported. But it's a big ecosystem; someone else may have built tools to automate it.

Comment: (That said, I don't see why asking users to install a Nix binary package via adding to the list of substituters is any different from adding a source of Debian packages or RPMs via `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` or equivalent and using `apt` or `yum` for the download; that's done in those worlds all the time).

Comment: Posted: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-build-and-distribute-binary-packages-with-nix/14439

Editing `sources.list.d` is not different, and I don't want users to do this either. I am looking for an equivalent to `rpm -i <filename>`.

Comment: BTW, re: "build a NAR file" -- that's what `nix-store --dump` does, and `nix-store --restore` installs it. NAR is also the serialization format that `nix-copy` creates and loads, and the format for content retrieved from a binary cache.

Comment: (oh, and it's `f`s instead of `t`s in "Duffy")

Comment: > oh, and it's fs instead of ts in "Duffy"

Ouch. Apologies! _fixed_

Comment: I noted that `nix copy` writes out the nar files of the package closure in a directory. I am tempted to write little "nix-import" script that runs `nix-store --restore` on all those nar files, to get the exact semantics I was looking for : )

Comment: I use a cachix private cache to distribute Hercules CI Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by JonRinger on [discourse](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-build-and-distribute-binary-packages-with-nix/14439), `nix copy` can be used for this purpose, as follows.

If we were to distribute nixpkgs.ag's as a package, we could run:

```
nix copy nixpkgs.ag --to file://ag.pkg 
# We now have a local directory `ag.pkg` which we can tar-up and distribute
# On the client machine, we run the following to install the package
nix copy --from file://ag.pkg nixpkgs.ag
```

See `nix copy --help` for some more details.

> Note: this program is EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change.